# Como llamar un archivo de sonido en Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, push-notification

Estoy haciendo que al presionar un boton se reproduzca un sonido, el problema con el codigo es que no logro como llamar, o donde ubicar el archivo `.MP3`

El archivo se llama `SonidoDePrueba` y lo agregue a `Resources > Drawable`, y a la carpeta general del proyecto.

Codigo:

```
    public void ReproducirSonido() 
    { 
       try 
       { 
         Android.Net.Uri notification = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.SonidoDePrueba); 
        //No funciona. Lanza error. No reconoce el SonidoDePrueba.
                            
         Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(this, notification); 
         r.Play(); 
       } 
       catch (Exception e) 
       { 
          e.Message.ToString(); 
       } 
    }
```

Tambien intente:

```
MediaPlayer player;
player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resources.Drawable.SonidoDePrueba);
player.Start();
```

Pero tampoco reconoce `Resources`.

Tambien intente:

```
public void ReproducirNotificacion()
    {
        try
        {
            var stream = GetStreamFromFile2("SonidoDePrueba.mp3");
            var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
            audio.Load(stream);
            audio.Play();

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            string LineErrorNumber = Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "Error: " + Ex.Message;
        }
    }

    System.IO.Stream GetStreamFromFile(string filename)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(AndroidApp).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProyectoUno." + filename);

        return stream;
    }
```

Pero tampoco encuentra ningún `stream`.

Ahora, en estos casos me supongo que el problema esta en que no encuentra el sonido porque el codigo logicamente debe estar bien y ser funcional; el punto es que para el Path algunos dicen que es con `/` otros que es con `.`, igual ya he probado con ambos, tambien no se si en el `"ProjectName"` debe ir el nombre de mi proyecto que se llama `ProyectoUno` o el nombre que luego le di a la app que es `AppSonido` que es como sale en el emulador.

Me podrían dar algún consejo especifico para mi caso por favor?

Comment: Es con el media player, tu le estas pasando drawable, osea un objeto que se puede dibujar y no un sonido. Pasa la dirrecion del archivo o intenta con un tipo raw en ves de drawable.

Comment: Pero como puedo hacer eso @OsAndNoTi? (C#) Es con lo que necesito ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La clase mediaplayer tiene metodos o en su constructor busca algo asi que reciba algo asi.

Comment: Esta de esta forma pero no me reconoce tampoco la carpeta RAW del audio. Checa: MediaPlayer player;
player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resources.Raw.SonidoDePrueba);
player.Start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de hacerlo es tan facil como esto:

**Void o linea para gatillar el sonido:**

```
public void ReproducirNotificacion()
        {
            try
            {
                FindAudioFile("sound.mp3");
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

**Void de lógica de acceso al audio:**

```
public void FindAudioFile(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var player = new MediaPlayer();
        var fd = global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
        player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
        {
            player.Start();
        };
        player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
        player.Prepare();
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

El audio tiene que estar (al menos en mi caso asi lo trabaje) en la carpeta `Assets` (`Xamarin.Android`).

y listo.

Answer (score 1):

El directorio `/Drawable` es exclusivo para imágenes.

Tienes dos opciones, el archivo .mp3 se debe agregar dentro de `/Resources` en el directorio `/raw`,

De esta forma cargarías el archivo .mp3 para reproducción desde el directorio `/raw`

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.SonidoDePrueba);
mediaPlayer.Start();
```

También puedes agregarlo dentro de `/Resources` en el directorio `/raw`, [revisa este ejemplo](https://www.godo.dev/tutorials/xamarin-forms-play-audio/):

```
public void Play(string pathToAudioFile)  
{  
  if (_mediaPlayer != null)  
  {  
    _mediaPlayer.Completion -= MediaPlayer_Completion;  
    _mediaPlayer.Stop();  
  }  
  
  var fullPath = pathToAudioFile;  
  
  Android.Content.Res.AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;  
  
  try  
  {  
    afd = Forms.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fullPath);  
  }  
  catch (Exception ex)  
  {  
    Console.WriteLine("Error openfd: " + ex);  
  }  
  if (afd != null)  
  {  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Length " + afd.Length);  
    if (_mediaPlayer == null)  
    {  
      _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();  
      _mediaPlayer.Prepared += (sender, args) =>  
      {  
        _mediaPlayer.Start();  
        _mediaPlayer.Completion += MediaPlayer_Completion;  
      };  
    }  
  
    _mediaPlayer.Reset();  
    _mediaPlayer.SetVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);  
  
    _mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor, afd.StartOffset, afd.Length);  
    _mediaPlayer.PrepareAsync();  
  }  
}
```